# maven processor plugin order of generated sources in a gwtp app

Tags: java, maven, gwtp

I'm using maven processor plugin to generate sources.

```
        <!-- Run annotation processors on src/home/java sources -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwtp-processors</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is that I have generated classes that are dependent on these generated classes.

E.g.

`com.project.client.application.event.DevInfoEvent.java` has a classmember of DevInfoDto
`com.project.shared.dto.generated.dev.DevInfoDto.java`

Both files are generated, but the problem is the DevInfoEvent is generated sooner, therefore I got an error that it can't resolve the DevInfoDto

When I run the `generate-sources` from eclipse for the second time, it is ok, because the DevInfoDto is already generated. But this behavior is not good me. (Don't want to run `compile` on the CI server twice).

Is there a way to tell `maven processor plugin` some order, in which it should generate classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make `com.project.client` and `com.project.shared` two different Maven projects, declare `shared` as a dependency of `client` and aggregate them as `<module>`s in a parent project. Such, when building this parent project, Maven's reactor takes care of the proper build order.

This also makes sense in another way: `shared` functionality is probably different to `client` functionality.